# Fiancee has Indefinite Leave to Remain, I am UK Citizen. Going to France for honeymoon

Tags: visas, schengen, france, zambian-citizens

My fiancee and I are going to France for our honeymoon.

I am a UK citizen, but she is a Zambian citizen with indefinite leave to remain in UK.

I understand we will need a visa for our travel, but we will be married when we set off. We are setting off one week after wedding. Should we apply now for her, providing all documentation etc, or after we are married, and not have to provide anything other than the marriage certificate?

Would one week be enough time?

Comment: *...and not have to provide anything other than the marriage certificate* Where do you get this from ?

Comment: @blackbird57 From the EU freedom of movement directive, though the real situation is somewhat more complex, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Even if one week *were* enough time, an application filed so soon after your wedding will risk scrutiny for a potential marriage of convenience.  In that case, you would need to present much of the same evidence you'd need to demonstrate your relationship before marrying.  It would be safer to gather that evidence now, in which case you should probably just apply now, since one week might indeed be too little time.

Comment: Someone with indefinite leave to remain in the UK isn't all that much of a concern for overstaying in Schengen.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's very true.  The chance of being challenged on a marriage of convenience is probably quite low.  If it were me, I'd want to play it safe and just get the permit early.  For someone else with different risk tolerance, or for whom the development of the evidence might be very burdensome, the conclusion could well be different.